# What would be the correct way to implement a "Try again" message for a simple guessing game?

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a text that says "Try again" to appear when the player guesses incorrectly. This is an extremely bare bones "game" but I started coding yesterday and I'm trying to learn all the basic functions and methods. This is the code:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_limit = 3
guess_count = 0
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input("Guess:"))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        break
else:
    print("You lost!")
```

I tried using another "else" function and another "if" function but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: _I tried using another "else" function_ Show us what you tried.  We can't point out what you did wrong if you don't show us the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print `'Try again'` after checking if the player guesses correctly. To avoid printing `'Try again'` in the last guess, use an additional `if` statement:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_limit = 3
guess_count = 0
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = int(input("Guess:"))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        break
    if guess_count < guess_limit: # add these two lines
        print('Try again')
else:
    print("You lost!")
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/RaggedGleamingMenus

Answer (score 2):

You can implement and ELSE statement, for continuing the loop:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_limit = 3
guess_count = 0
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    won = False
    guess = int(input("Guess:"))
    guess_count += 1

    if guess == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        won = True
        break

    # If wrong, goes in here.
    else:
        # Just prints, and continues the loop
        print('Try again')

# After the loop, if not won, prints lost.
if not won:
    print("You lost!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Exchange, sebas!

Here's how I would implement the "try again" message:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_limit = 3
guess_count = 0
while guess_count < guess_limit:  # this could also just be `while True:` since the `if` will always break out
    guess = int(input("Guess:"))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        break
    else:
        if guess_count == guess_limit:
            print("You lost!")
            break
        else:
            print("Try again!")
```

As the comment says, the while statement could actually just be an infinite loop of `while True:` since the `if` statement logic will always eventually break out of the loop.

---

**UPDATE**: I initially said that the `while`/`else` wasn't valid. Actually, it turns out that it is -- thanks, blhsing, for pointing that out. I would probably leave it out, since to me it makes the "try again" bit of the logic easier for my brain, but it's a nifty feature and could easily be used as well, like so:

```
secret_number = 9
guess_limit = 3
guess_count = 0
while guess_count < guess_limit:  # this could also just be `while True:` since the `if` will always break out
    guess = int(input("Guess:"))
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        break
    else:
        if guess_count < guess_limit:
            print("Try again!")
else:
    print("You lost!")
```

Comment: The `while-else` statement is perfectly valid in Python and is a preferred way of implementing the "You lost" condition Pythonically. Please read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) of the `else` clause in a loop.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for clarifying that the else at the end isn't needed.

Comment: blhsing: oh, sheesh, you're right! That's nice and clean! I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @blhsing I tried the code without the else "part" (what is part of a statement called by the way?) and it still printed only when the player loses. Would this work in all cases and programs or is this because of a specific reason?

Answer (score -1):

add import random
and set secret_number = random.randint(0,9)

you don't need to add the 'else' statement at the last line
it should be just "print("You lost!")"

Comment: you don't actually answer the OP's question on how to implement a "try again"